# Posts page only shows one post

Tags: posts

I have an old blog that I have kept up to date with the latest Wordpress version, plugins and theme updates over the years. But somewhere along the way the posts page stopped working properly. It presently only shows a link for one post. Furthermore, it is just the link, no graphic or summary is displayed. I disabled the theme and all the plugins as a test but the result is the same. I recreated the page that is named as the posts page too, all to get the same result. [This is a link to the page.](http://www.veraclaritas.com/leading-articles/) What am I missing?

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and look for error messages. Output stops right after that link, so it's likely there's an error halting execution.

Comment: That was it. Apparently the theme I use in one of its updates required the Options Framework plugin. Without it, a certain function was undefined. Thus the error and the breaking of the posts page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment above, apparently the theme I use in one of its updates required the Options Framework plugin. Without it, a certain function was undefined. Thus the error and the breaking of the posts page. Installing the plugin solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Reading. Change the 'Blog pages show at most' value. I'd bet it's set at `1`.

It's also possible that your theme settings have a similar value, so look into the Customization pages of the current theme. Could be anywhere, so poke around a bit.

(I believe it has nothing to do with permalinks, core files, etc, as posited by another answer. Although a theme setting 'might' do it. Changing the default theme will not change the "Blog pages show at most" value.)

Comment: I checked. It is set at 15. And that wouldn't explain why the accompanying graphic and summary are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the "Blog pages show at most" settings in the reading section go to settings -> Readings and increase the "Blog pages show at most"

Comment: As noted above, I checked. It is set at 15. And that wouldn't explain why the accompanying graphic and summary are missing.